# How to use PKCE without secret using Spring Security Oauth?

Tags: spring-security, pkce, spring-authorization-server

I am following this tutorial at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-pkce-secret-clients

In this example it is using PKCE with Spring Security OAuth.  However, I noticed that it is still setting the client-secret value.  I thought PKCE didn't require a secret as it is meant for a public client who don't want to expose that secret in a mobile or a javascript app.

If I comment out the clientSecret value then the login does not work.  Here is the main PCKE client configuration on the authorization-server saving using jpa (updated this method to persist using postconstruct annotation):

```
     @PostConstruct
    private void saveRegisteredClient() {
        final String clientId = "pkce-client";
        clientRepository.deleteAll(); //this is for dev purpose only

        RegisteredClient registeredClient = jpaRegisteredClientRepository.findByClientId(clientId);
        if (registeredClient != null) {
            LOG.info("registered client exists");
        }
        else {
            registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/pkce")
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                    //.postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/logged-out")
                    .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                    .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                    .scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
                    .scope("message.read")
                    .scope("message.write")
                    .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                            .requireProofKey(true).build())
                    .build();

            jpaRegisteredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);
            LOG.info("saved registeredClient");
        }
    }
```

(Update: The following is my pkce-client configuration in application.yaml):

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          katlock:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8085
        registration: 
          pkce:
            provider: katlock
            client-id: pkce-client
            scope: openid,email
```

Here is My client trace log after attempting login:

```
2023-04-29T10:42:38.404-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /login/oauth2/code/pkce' doesn't match 'null /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2023-04-29T10:42:38.404-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/login/oauth2/code/pkce'; against '/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
2023-04-29T10:42:38.733-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthenticationWebFilter      : Authentication failed: [invalid_request] 
2023-04-29T10:42:38.733-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy  : Redirecting to '/login?error'
2023-04-29T10:42:38.737-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'null /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2023-04-29T10:42:38.737-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'null /login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
2023-04-29T10:42:38.738-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/login', method=GET}
2023-04-29T10:42:38.738-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2023-04-29T10:42:38.738-06:00 DEBUG 66101 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : matched
```

The following is the trace log from the spring-authorization-server:

```
2023-04-29T10:42:38.198-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1291/0x0000000801491e70@5c450960, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7c5fbde4, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7021bb55, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@a3f1f32, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter@1dc987b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@10efb806, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7d5176d6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4e6add8d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@4512f5f1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@1722ede1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@671561b9, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@6bca6c4c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@30a99b85, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@6b6cf3c1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@580a5b6e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@14927cd4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6023b54f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@128ebca1, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@e9947af, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@430dbcb0, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@c680819, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@273e622f, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@2ac00dc9]] (1/2)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.200-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5eaa4ed0, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@462deb2b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3f9ee527, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@104e6540, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3344c1d7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@57330423, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@11f752d1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3b22bcad, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@381c826c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2a41d17a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@58a5b69c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@13563e64, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@73b034ca, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@c3e5e3c]] (2/2)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.202-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login
2023-04-29T10:42:38.205-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.205-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.205-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.205-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.205-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/14)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.207-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.207-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.207-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/14)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.207-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.362-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-04-29T10:42:38.362-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/2)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.363-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionEventPublisher      : Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionIdChangedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5a48451d]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.363-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from 8BFE6EA832F8D2184E77CDA4EEA1F88A
2023-04-29T10:42:38.364-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with CsrfAuthenticationStrategy (2/2)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.364-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.s.w.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy  : Replaced CSRF Token
2023-04-29T10:42:38.364-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=8BFE6EA832F8D2184E77CDA4EEA1F88A], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5a48451d]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.364-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=8BFE6EA832F8D2184E77CDA4EEA1F88A], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.365-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8085/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=pkce-client&scope=openid%20email&state=jyGXRa-WQVB6Yn7MIRiD2sQ08dJb1-oQHQaqfN5Vo90%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/pkce&nonce=R7viP02frx6WgoaY8xi9Vvr3yEOzALxEgsUCtc46q3U&code_challenge=4n3E5Km3qT4lDmVkMU9QBMp2YRpXYXT8sx_qA2eTIf0&code_challenge_method=S256&continue
2023-04-29T10:42:38.365-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.367-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1291/0x0000000801491e70@5c450960, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7c5fbde4, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7021bb55, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@a3f1f32, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter@1dc987b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@10efb806, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7d5176d6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4e6add8d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@4512f5f1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@1722ede1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@671561b9, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@6bca6c4c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@30a99b85, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@6b6cf3c1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@580a5b6e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@14927cd4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6023b54f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@128ebca1, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@e9947af, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@430dbcb0, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@c680819, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@273e622f, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@2ac00dc9]] (1/2)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.368-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=pkce-client&scope=openid%20email&state=jyGXRa-WQVB6Yn7MIRiD2sQ08dJb1-oQHQaqfN5Vo90%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/pkce&nonce=R7viP02frx6WgoaY8xi9Vvr3yEOzALxEgsUCtc46q3U&code_challenge=4n3E5Km3qT4lDmVkMU9QBMp2YRpXYXT8sx_qA2eTIf0&code_challenge_method=S256&continue
2023-04-29T10:42:38.368-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.370-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.370-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.370-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationServerContextFilter (4/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.370-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (5/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.372-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (6/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.372-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1291/0x0000000801491e70@5c450960, org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@6cd1ee]]]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.372-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (7/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.373-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.373-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (8/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.373-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (9/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.373-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=8BFE6EA832F8D2184E77CDA4EEA1F88A], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]] from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2023-04-29T10:42:38.373-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider (1/13)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.402-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/pkce?code=NFXzAwY7OBR2fwFfCvY8fkhPwpCutePxi1-H77yRhKUlC8ShX65XeMJxJxX9ovoLeW3Z2ugvDGhNif2unYAnqqZ26qPOZKKrrQrrs7YE-f_aqkXCwdim3FriyKddoOG4&state=jyGXRa-WQVB6Yn7MIRiD2sQ08dJb1-oQHQaqfN5Vo90%3D
2023-04-29T10:42:38.402-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.704-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1291/0x0000000801491e70@5c450960, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7c5fbde4, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7021bb55, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@a3f1f32, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter@1dc987b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@10efb806, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7d5176d6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4e6add8d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@4512f5f1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@1722ede1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@671561b9, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@6bca6c4c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@30a99b85, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@6b6cf3c1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@580a5b6e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@14927cd4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6023b54f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@128ebca1, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@e9947af, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@430dbcb0, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@c680819, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@273e622f, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@2ac00dc9]] (1/2)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.705-06:00 DEBUG 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/token
2023-04-29T10:42:38.705-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.706-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.707-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.708-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationServerContextFilter (4/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.708-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (5/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.708-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (6/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.710-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1291/0x0000000801491e70@5c450960, org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@6cd1ee]]]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.710-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (7/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.710-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-04-29T10:42:38.711-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (8/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.711-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (9/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.711-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter (10/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.711-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter (11/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.712-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter (12/22)
2023-04-29T10:42:38.713-06:00 TRACE 65972 --- [nio-8085-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `@Configuration` demonstrates a public client setup for Spring Authorization Server:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        // ...
        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        // ...
        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient publicClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:4200")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(true)
                        .requireProofKey(true)
                        .build()
                )
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(publicClient);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll mention that you can absolutely use PKCE with a confidential client, which is what the article you linked to is demonstrating.

If you do remove the `clientSecret` setting, you will also need to change the `clientAuthenticationMethod` to `ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE`.

You would also want to remove the `authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)` setting since it does not make sense for public clients.

**Note:** Keep in mind that Spring Authorization Server [will not issue a refresh token](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390) with the token request for public clients, in which case you can also remove `authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)`.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your response.  I did like you suggested but I keep getting "Invalid credentials error" after log-in.  I have pasted my auth-client config above for your reference.

Comment: Sorry, can you paste the trace logs from the flow? Otherwise, I'm not sure. Enable trace with `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`.

Comment: Hi Steve, I have just added my trace logs for the pkce-client and and pkce-authorization server.  The logs are after the login attemp.

Comment: Thanks. There's something wrong on the client side. Can you share any Java configuration for the client?

Comment: I think the implicit flow supported it but is not recommended anymore.  So I think I have my answer.

Comment: Sorry, @Katlock, I don't think I understand. "I think the implicit flow supported it but is not recommended anymore." Are you saying implicit flow supported PKCE but authorization code does not?

Comment: So reading thru documentation I understood that implicit flow allows public client but reading this documentation and other frontend draft mentions about using bff for the ui.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. To be clear, PKCE is supported by SAS. However, when it is the only credential used, the client is considered a *public client* and is not issued a refresh token. When configuring a BFF (as a confidential client with a secret), you can still enable PKCE for extra security.

Comment: However, I would still like to see a public client example of Authorization code grant with PKCE.  I have been reading this documentation https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps which is great as well.

Comment: Are you looking for a javascript client example?

Comment: Take a look at our [recent SpringOne presentation](https://youtu.be/_doNO1DbAiw?t=893).

Comment: I checked out your presentation on the Public Client using PKCE and also the github repo.  I was able to checkout github repo and checked out at commit '92acf9ab'.  I ran the angular client and had the same client id.  I still get error after logging in.

Comment: I just checked out the same commit and ran `angular-client`, `demo-authorizationserver` and `messages-resource` applications. Then browsed to `http://127.0.0.1:4200` and everything works for me.

Comment: For whatever reason I keep seeing the same error.  I went back to my spring-auth client again.  I also saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732497/spring-boot-authorization-server-not-redirectly-back-to-configured-redirect-ur.  When I use my spring auth client and after logging in successfully  I see this error: ` o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/error?continue` on the authorization server.  I am not sure why I am seeing that error.

Comment: is there anything special that I need to add to my `etc/hosts` file when running in dev?

Comment: Not as long as you are using "127.0.0.1:4200" as the host for your client. If you use `localhost:4200` you will have issues because the demo is not configured to use `localhost`, and should not use it. If that doesn't resolve the issue, I'm not sure what else would cause it.

Comment: So I got the angular client working finally at that commit.  By default, the angular wanted me to use http://localhost:4200 but the http://127.0.0.1:4200 didn't work.  So I had to do the following on dev when starting the angular client: ` ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`. to get this working

Comment: I do have a follow up question on whether my oauth client configuration is correct for a public client?

Comment: The `RegisteredClient` from the question looks correct. If you have a more specific question, feel free to add a new SO question and I'll take a look.